# OpenLayers - ArcGIS Vector Tiles - styling with ol-MapBox-Style

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

UPDATE 2 **********************************

It seems as if I have run in to this exact problem. I guess olms currently does not support "local" ArcGIS Server Vector Tiles :-(

[Github issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style/issues/344)

Original question:

I have a local ArcGIS Server that serves a Vector Tile service.

[Vector Tile](https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer/)

The data can be consumed in OpenLayers, but I have a problem styling it using olms.js

```
const basemapURL = "https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer/resources/styles/root.json";
      
olms(map, basemapURL);
```

I get the error: "Error accessing data for source 'esri'"

[The style json can be found here:](https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer/resources/styles/root.json?f=json)

Inspecting the json it does not seem to have the same content as the Vector Tiles from https://basemaps-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/styles/

The problem can be seen in this Codepen (in the console):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/larssoe/pen/YzxjPeG?editors=1000)

Any help would be much appreciated! :-)

UPDATE **********************************************

This is driving me crazy :-)

The style json served by ArcGIS initially looks like this:  `{"version":8,"sprite":"../sprites/sprite","glyphs":"../fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf","sources":{"esri":{"type":"vector","bounds":[12.0044,55.9649,12.4197,56.1373],"minzoom":0,"maxzoom":15,"scheme":"xyz","url":"/../../"}},"layers":[{"id":"sde270.SDE.Plandistrikter/0","type":"vector","source":"esri","source-layer":"sde270.SDE.Plandistrikter","layout":{"line-cap":"round","line-join":"round"},"paint":{"line-color":"#FF0000","line-width":0.933333}}]}`

I have changed the file to this:

`{"version":8,"sprite":"../sprites/sprite","glyphs":"../fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf","sources":{"esri":{"type":"vector","bounds":[12.0044,55.9649,12.4197,56.1373],"minzoom":0,"maxzoom":15,"scheme":"xyz","url":"https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer?f=json", "tiles":["https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf"]}},"layers":[{"id":"sde270.SDE.Plandistrikter/0","type":"vector","source":"esri","source-layer":"sde270.SDE.Plandistrikter","layout":{"line-cap":"round","line-join":"round"},"paint":{"line-color":"#FF0000","line-width":0.933333}}]}`

With "https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer?f=json" in the url-property (instead of "/../"../") I no longer get the "Error accessing data for source esri" in the console. But I have to remove "?f=json" from all urls. (see CodePen at the bottom)

For now my challenges are:

- Vector tiles are epsg:25832 and in the Codepen I have tried to implement this.
- Vector tiles are not shown in map, but no errors in console
- When changing the style (root.json) on the server - the layer no longer works on ArcGIS Server JS API or when shown on OpenLayers without olms.
  So this can not be the way ahead. The original simple CodePen now shows the error "No sprites found." in the console...
- ArcGIS Server does not return json by default, ArcGIS.com does. I guess olms assumes ArcGIS Server behaves like ArcGIS.com?

Here is the Codepen with EPSG:25832 and with "?f=json" added inside the root.json.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/larssoe/pen/OJjwaWK)

[CodePen with the same layer but without styling/olms](https://jsfiddle.net/larssoe/0vyw2Lg5/242/)

Comment: The style json contains both tile and url entries.  It seems url is used by default if specified, but their is no tilejson at that url.

Comment: Also you should use a more recent version of olms.js to work correctly with OpenLayers 6.

Comment: I have tried using the newest version of olms 6.5.1 with the same outcome. Can you help me a little further with the tilejson? https://basemaps-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/ contains the array source.esri.tiles but the vector tiles from my server does not? This resource contains tileinfo but no styling? https://bragdev3.gis.dk/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Plandistrikter2/VectorTileServer?f=json

Comment: If the url in the style json ended `?f=json` I think it would work, Without that it returns a html layout which cannot be handled by something design for Mapbox compliant jsons.

Comment: Mike I really, really appreciate yout input. Adding ?f=json to the url does not make a difference, but when adding it inside the root.json it does. But there still seem to be some properties missing in the style json compared to the style json from the basemaps from arcgis.com. Pretty frustrating... Would you take a look at the updated question? Sorry it is a mess :-)